# Why does my tap counter go back to 1 when it gest higher than 10?

Tags: swift, if-statement, comparison, counter

I am trying to just simply have a button you tap and it adds 1 to a label. If that label is below 3 print its below three. If it's above 3 print that it's above. This works up until 10 which then prints out it's below three even though the label still shows 10 or higher.

```
var counter = 0
@IBOutlet weak var count: UILabel!

  @IBAction func testigbutton(_ sender: UIButton) {
      
       counter = counter + 1
       count.text = String(format: "%i", counter)
    
    if count.text! < "3" {
        
        print("Less than 3")
    } else if count.text! > "10" {
               
        print("More than 3")
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Comparison of `String` is done character by character.

`"9"` is greater than `"3"` because the character `9` is above the character `3` if sorted.

`"10"` is less than `"3"` because, as this does character by character comparison, `"1"` is less than `"3"` and it finishes there.

If you need to do numerical comparison (an actual *number* instead of strings), use:

`if Int(count.text!) < 3 { ... } else { ... }`

Note that I'm comparing an actual `Int` and not a `String`.

Answer (score 1):

Change the line

```swift
if count.text! < "3" {
```

to:

```swift
if counter < 3 {
```

This way you'll compare numbers by their order instead of strings by their lexicographic order.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are comparing a string, it checks each character. In other words, instead of comparing to 10, it compares to 1 then to 0. Since 1 is <3, it prints that. All you need to fix this is either to simply compare to your counter variable, or cast it to an Int or Double with something like
`Int(count.text!)`